# Plugin settings are rendered wrong

Tags: plugin-development, templating, plugins, settings

I'm trying to create a craft plugin but I have problems with rendering the settings.

Right now I used the same way like [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/plugin-settings) so this is my plugin code

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class testPlugin extends BasePlugin
{


    function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Test');
    }

    public function getVersion()
    {
        return '0.1';
    }

    public function getDeveloper()
    {
        return 'Secondred Newmedia GmbH';
    }

    public function getDeveloperUrl()
    {
        return 'http://www.secondred.de';
    }

    public function getSourceLanguage()
    {
        return 'de';
    }

    protected function defineSettings()
    {
        return array(
            'accountID' => array(AttributeType::Mixed)
        );
    }

    public function getSettingsHtml()
    {
        return craft()->templates->render('test/tools/config', array(
            'settings' => $this->getSettings()
        ));
    }

    public function hasCpSection()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is my config.twig

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{% set page = 'Settings'|t %}
{% set title = 'Settings'|t %}

{% set content %}
    <div class="pane">
        <p>Hello Craft</p>
    </div>

{% endset %}
```

But it always ends up like this 
[image]
The menu is always rendered inside my plugin Settings and If I just use

```
public function getSettingsUrl()
{
    return 'test/tools/configuration';
}
```

the template is rendered correctly but I can't pass my variables anymore (of course in that example there are no, but I use some in my real plugin I just didn't want to show you 1000 lines of unneeded code) .

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? My actual real plugin is nearly ready and this is the last error I have to fix but I don't know how. I need your help thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `extends` and `set content`. The settings twig-code is rendered in a container inside the CP anyways:

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

<p>Hello Craft</p>
```

Comment: Since I can't upvote your post I'll do it in this way, thank you very much.